# Combine drainage streams and watersheds

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, layers, clip, watershed

I have a question regarding ArcMap. Lets say I have a .shp with watersheds and a .shp with drainage lines. How can I combine both, so that I can display single watersheds and the length of their inner streams. Just like in the nice picture below.

[image]

I want to access the length of the stream segments inside each catchment. I have tried several clipping methods but have still no useful results.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using [Identity](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Identity/00080000000n000000/), with the streams as the input and watersheds as the identity?

Comment: That did not help, but thank you. There must be a way!

Comment: Note there is a difference between IdentiTy and IdentiFy. Identity does require an Advanced license, but should do what you want assuming (as radouxju's answer notes) your watersheds are polygons and not lines. Identity is one of a few Overlay operations that would get what you want, such as Intersect or Union, but it's important to note they give slightly different results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to make sure that your watershed are polygons. If not : feature to polygon.

Then you can make the intersection (intersect_analysis) between your watershed and your lines.

You'll end up with lines that have the fields of the waershed as an attribute table. You can then use summary statstics to have the total length for each watershed. Note that if you don't work in a geodatabase, you need to re-calculate the length of your lines before you do the summary statistics (otherwise it will be the length before intersecting)